# How to convert dos2unix csv file with python script

Tags: python, dos2unix

I want to convert a csv file into dos2unix format using python in windows.
Rightnow I am doing manually by placing csv file in workarea(server) and run command in putty.[Command :  dos2unix file_received filename]

Answer (score 3):

`dos2unix` (as I recall) pretty much only strips the trailing linefeeds off each line. So, there's two ways you can do this.

```
with open(filename, "w") as fout: 
    with open(file_received, "r") as fin:
        for line in fin:
            line = line.replace('\r\n', '\n')
            fout.write(line)
```

or you can use subprocess to call the UNIX command directly. **WARNING**: This is bad since you're using a parameter `file_received`, and people could potentially tag executable commands into it.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call([ 'dos2unix', file_received, filename, shell=False])
```

I haven't tested the above. The `shell=False` (the default) means a UNIX shell won't be called for the process. This is good to avoid someone inserting commands into the parameters, but you may have to have `shell=True` in order for the command to work right.

Answer (score 1):

The following code would do the trick:

```
import csv
out_file_path = 
in_file_path = 
with open(out_file_path,'w',newline='') as output_file:
    writer = csv.writer(output_file, dialect=csv.unix_dialect)
    with open(in_file_path,newline='') as input_file:
        reader = csv.reader(input_file)
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row)
```